# How to change the format of a Duration?

Tags: spring, duration

I have a Spring API that lets me create and return a list of calls. A call has a duration (can be in seconds, minutes or hours) so I used the type `Duration` in my API and the type `Interval` in my Postgres database.

I am able to create a call with no problem as well as return the list of all calls but the duration is displayed in this format: `PT15S` for 15 seconds, `PT5M30S` for 5 minutes and 30 seconds for example.

It does the job but I would like to display it in a better format: 15s or 00:05:30 for example. I couldn't find a clear answer on where and how exactly to do this without having to change the type (I would like to keep Duration in both my entity and my DTO).

```
public class MyCallEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "date", nullable = false)
    private Instant date;

    @Type(PostgreSQLIntervalType.class)
    @Column(name = "duration", columnDefinition = "interval", nullable = false)
    private Duration duration;
}


public class MyCallDto {
    private Long id;
    private Instant date;
    private Duration duration;
}
```

I tried using the `@JsonFormat` annotation with pattern HOURS, MINUTES and SECONDS: `@JsonFormat(pattern = "MINUTES")` but this doesn't do anything, I keep getting PT15S whenever I display the list of all calls or just one call.

Is there a way to do this without having to change the type at some point?

Comment: I would strongly recommend sending the standard format over the wire. If you want to convert it to some other form for a human to read, do so at the edge, where they're viewing it (e.g. HTML element, GUI, stdout).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your dto:

```
public class MyCallDto {
  //...
  private Duration duration;
  
  @JsonGetter("duration")
  public long getDurationInMinutes() {
    return duration.toMinutes();
  }
  
  @JsonSetter("duration")
  public void DurationInMinutes(long duration) {
    this.duration= Duration.ofMinutes(duration);
  }
}
```

Have a look on this https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations If you want to get more informations about that implementation.

Comment: This does the trick, However, it only displays the minutes, I replaced it with seconds and then I'm able to format the seconds in the frontend of the app. Thank you !